# jni.h not found with JNI CPP gradle

Tags: java, c++, gradle, java-native-interface

I'm trying to make a Java library with some CPP code using JNI and gradle. I followed the steps here: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/setting-up-jni-development-in-gradle-project.html

But this just shows steps for setting up JNI with C. I need to do it with CPP. I changed the `c` directory to `cpp`, updated the code to cpp and used the cpp plugin in build.gradle file.
But on building it gives me this error:

```
> Task :compileHelloSharedLibraryHelloCpp FAILED
In file included from /home/karthik/gradle_try/hello/src/hello/cpp/hello.cpp:1:0:
/home/karthik/gradle_try/hello/src/hello/cpp/hello.h:2:10: fatal error: jni.h: No such file or directory
 #include <jni.h>
          ^~~~~~~
compilation terminated.
```

Here's my `build.gradle` file:

```
import org.gradle.internal.jvm.Jvm

/*
 * This file was generated by the Gradle 'init' task.
 *
 * This generated file contains a sample Java Library project to get you started.
 * For more details take a look at the Java Libraries chapter in the Gradle
 * User Manual available at https://docs.gradle.org/6.2.2/userguide/java_library_plugin.html
 */

plugins {
    // Apply the java-library plugin to add support for Java Library
    id 'java-library'
    id 'cpp'
}

repositories {
    // Use jcenter for resolving dependencies.
    // You can declare any Maven/Ivy/file repository here.
    jcenter()
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    // This dependency is exported to consumers, that is to say found on their compile classpath.
    api 'org.apache.commons:commons-math3:3.6.1'

    // This dependency is used internally, and not exposed to consumers on their own compile classpath.
    implementation 'com.google.guava:guava:28.1-jre'

    // Use JUnit test framework
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
}
sourceCompatibility = 1.8
targetCompatibility = 1.8

test {
    systemProperty "java.library.path", file("${buildDir}/libs/hello/shared").absolutePath
}

model {
    platforms {
        x64 {
            architecture "x64"
        }
    }

    components {
        hello(NativeLibrarySpec) {
            binaries.all {
                if (targetPlatform.operatingSystem.macOsX) {
                    cCompiler.args '-I', "${Jvm.current().javaHome}/include"
                    cCompiler.args '-I', "${Jvm.current().javaHome}/include/darwin"
                    cCompiler.args '-mmacosx-version-min=10.4'
                    linker.args '-mmacosx-version-min=10.4'
                } else if (targetPlatform.operatingSystem.linux) {
                    cCompiler.args '-I', "${Jvm.current().javaHome}/include"
                    cCompiler.args '-I', "${Jvm.current().javaHome}/include/linux"
                    cCompiler.args '-D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64'
                } else if (targetPlatform.operatingSystem.windows) {
                    cCompiler.args "-I${Jvm.current().javaHome}/include"
                    cCompiler.args "-I${Jvm.current().javaHome}/include/win32"
                    linker.args "Shlwapi.lib", "Advapi32.lib"
                } else if (targetPlatform.operatingSystem.freeBSD) {
                    cCompiler.args '-I', "${Jvm.current().javaHome}/include"
                    cCompiler.args '-I', "${Jvm.current().javaHome}/include/freebsd"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

test.dependsOn 'helloSharedLibrary'
```

Other relevant files:

`xyz.h`

```
#include<iostream>

class xyz {
    xyz(){}
    void print();
};
```

`xyz.cpp`

```
#include "xyz.h"

void xyz::print(){
    std::cout<<"Hello CPP\n";
}
```

`hello.h`

```
#include <jni.h>
/* Header for class hello_Library */

#ifndef _Included_hello_Library
#define _Included_hello_Library
#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" {
#endif

JNIEXPORT void JNICALL Java_hello_Library_print
  (JNIEnv *, jobject);

#ifdef __cplusplus
}
#endif
#endiff
#endif
```

`hello.cpp`

```
#include "hello.h"
#include "xyz.h"

void
Java_hello_Library_print(JNIEnv *env, jobject obj)
{
    xyz o();
    o.print();
}
```

`Library.java`

```
package hello;

public class Library {
    public boolean someLibraryMethod() {
        return true;
    }
    public native void print();
    static {
        System.loadLibrary("hello");
    }
}
```

I do not get this error when I try the JNI C implementation, and it works as expected. Any ideas on why this is happening and how to solve it?

Comment: Haven't tried it, but is there also something called "cppCompiler"? Maybe you have to set includes for that.

Comment: Yep, that's it! Thanks!

Comment: @user2543253 how can I use the jar and shared library built here in another java program?

Comment: Put the jar in `-classpath` and the library's folder in `-Djava.library.path=`. Make sure you have any library dependencies in your operating system's library path.